# Facebook Feed Dialog: Post not showing up on friend's wall even though I get a response id

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am creating an app on facebook and I am trying to post to a friend's wall.  I'm using the facebook javascript SDK and the FB.ui method to do this.  In short here is my code:

```
function test() {

var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      to: '######'
    };

function callback(response) {
      alert(response['post_id']);
    }

FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Note that I made this code very simple for testing purposes.

When I run it, a facebook feed dialog opens correctly and at the top says "Post Story to friendsname's Wall".  I type in a message and press Share.  My alert pops up with a response['post_id'] number.  Because there is a response['post_id'] the story should've been posted successfully right?  However when I navigate to the friend's wall there is no story.  I've tried this multiple times in slightly different ways and haven't been able to get it to work.  If I remove the 'to' parameter and simply post to my own wall it -does- work.  So for some reason, posting to a friend's wall breaks it?

I know it's a rather broad question but I was wondering if anybody had any ideas why this doesn't work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem may be because your application is in sandbox mode - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

> When testing your apps, place them into Sandbox Mode. **This hides your
>   app entirely from all users who you have not authorized in the
>   developer app to see the app,** for the roles described below. Please
>   note that when your app is in Sandbox Mode, you cannot call any API
>   calls on behalf of users who cannot see your app.

Basically, if your application is in sandbox mode, nothing your application does can be seen by users who have not authorized your application **or** by users that have not been specifically listed in the "roles" within your applications settings.

Remove you application from sandbox mode or add some users to specific "roles" within your application.

Comment: Wow that is awesome - yep that's the answer.  All I had to do was disable sandbox mode.  Also had to define a privacy policy but thats a different animal.  Anyways - thanks so much, I don't know how long that would've taken me to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Be aware of the requirement of a privacy policy - Facebook can and will close you down if you fail to specify the required policies...  Happy coding!